# How To Import Google Play service in Eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I use ADT Eclipse for Progrmming android.And Now I Want Use New Google APi for maps and use Google Play service.Now when Import Libary in Eclipse and added in my Project it's Error:

http://p30droid.com/Uploader/do.php?img=132

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html

How to Resolve This Problem..thanks

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you have at the moment is that you are missing a library project in your application project. At a guess - you may not have imported that library into your workspace or you may not have defined it as a library (you tick "is library" in the library project itself).

Comment: its not work for me,,Beacuse I want Use google play service not play game service

Comment: Sorry - I misread that - the first part of my answer is still relevant.